# Linphone call gets put on hold when mobile phone receives incoming call

Tags: linphone

I've searched various sources, but I can't find my issue described anywhere, let alone resolved.
The problem I am trying to resolve is this, when I have answered a call using Linphone on Android and I am talking, if another call comes in on the mobile phone's number (SIM, non-IP) then the Linphone call gets put on hold. To make matters worse, I can't find a way to get the call back from hold after dismissing the second call.
This the Linphone client app downloaded and installed from Google Play. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's expected. This is made so the sound of the IP call doesn't get mixed with the sound of the GSM call.
Check Android's audio focus for more details about this.